# User can't see items from list on site that was archived

Tags: list-item, archive

I have a site that was recently archived and set to Read Only in Central Admin. This site only has one list.I have a user with Full Control who can't view the items in that list. When I access the list I can see the items just fine but when the user attempts to access the same list within the archived site the items that display for me is non existent to the user. Can someone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: When the list was moved to the archive site, did the permissions get carried over too? Or did you just copy the content?

Comment: The permissions got moved as well. In the archived site the user has Full Control rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Under List Settings>Advanced Settings>Item-level Permissions. There is a Radio Button on this row that displays Read All Items and has to be selected for users to view.